# Angular initial load all the es js bundle files at once

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have deployed a my angular website in PROD server with used --prod to create the production build.
When I load my site in Incognito mode, all the es js files are loader rather then the required file.

I have even implemented the lazy loading, but still not luck.
Please find the attached image of network call for the same.
[JS Network Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ4Yc.png)

Please let me know as to how we can restrict only the required js file to be loaded

Comment: There is nothing we can do without code. Are you sure you are not using the lazy components immediately after loading the app?

Comment: Yes, as the initial load is the login page.

Comment: Please post your code. It's really difficult to help you without it. At least a part of the affected code.

Comment: Oh, it is actually your service-worker, that triest to pre-fetch every part of the app, to save on loading times down the line...

Comment: Yes.. the service-worker was calling all the files in the initial code due to pre-fetch strategy. I changed it to lazy and it solved the problem a bit.